# How to access a map within a map in C++ ..? Performance issue?

Tags: c++

```
typedef map<int, string> iMap;
typedef map<double, innerMap> OutMap;

OutMap mx;

map<double, iMap >::iterator it_out;
map<int, string>::iterator it_i;

for ( it_out=mx.begin() ; it_out != mx.end(); it_out++ ) {
   cout << "\n\nNew element\n" << (*it_out).first << endl;
   for( it_i=(*it_out).second.begin(); it_i != (*it_out).second.end(); it_out++)
     cout << (*it_i).first << " => " << (*it_i).second << endl;
}
```

I'm pretty sure the above code is fine...
Is there any performance issue...?

Comment: That depends. How fast is it and how fast do you want it to be?

Comment: You need to go deeper...

Comment: `std::map` is reasonably fast overall, but is it not performant enough for you? C++11 (and many implementations already provide similar) provide `std::unordered_map` if you don't need the ordering of `std::map`.

Comment: Is there any reason you can't use a `std::Pair<double, int>`?

Comment: @MikeBantegui he may occasionally need all the maps for a given double, and the performance difference is small.

Comment: @MooingDuck: With lexicographic ordering on the pair, all the elements with the same `double` value map are next to each other in iteration order. This could be exploited.

Comment: @KerrekSB: I know about `find_lower_bound`, but having them separate is definitely easier to conceptualize, and not (much) slower at runtime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It cannot be improved further, except that

- You can use pre-increment instead of post-increment, i.e `++it_out` instead of `it_out++`.
- You can use `'\n'` instead of `endl` in the cout. Using `'\n'` would improve the performance of output operation by reasonable margin, because `endl` first puts `'\n'` in the output buffer, and then flushes it to the destination (`stdout` in this case) which makes it slow operation.

Note that you should increment `it_i` (as opposed to `it_out`) in the inner `for` loop. I suppose that is a typo.